# Empty view not centered when using CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout and ViewPager/Fragment

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

In my view hierarchy, I got a

```
CoordinatorLayout
+- AppBarLayout
+- ViewPager (hosting my fragments)
   +- FrameLayout (within the fragment's view hierarchy)
      +- RecyclerView
      +- LinearLayout (my empty view for the list/recyclerview)
```

My AbbBarLayout gives room when the RecyclerView within a fragment in the ViewPager is scrolled up.

BUT: for the loading information I use the corresponding view group (the LinearLayout) which shares the same FrameLayout as the RecyclerView.

Problem is: the shown information is not centered on the screen any more as it is pushed downwards by the CoordinatorLayout to give room for scrolling up.

How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace `FrameLayout` with `CoordinatorLayout` and add `android:layout_marginBottom="?actionBarSize"` to `LinearLayout`.